# Gradle CreateDebugCoverageReport doesn't run local unit tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I'm using jacoco for code coverage. It runs (`./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport`) fine and generates code coverage for all the `androidTest` cases. However, it doesn't run the local unit tests, and hence doesn't compute the code coverage by these tests. How can I achieve all test cases including local to run and code coverage for all. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any pointers will be great.

I can successfully run all the local unit tests on JVM with `./gradlew testDebugUnitTest`

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped. https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa#.r2y0v7b5n

BIG SHOUT OUT FOR THE AUTHOR.

Comment: I have still not been able to resolve this issue, any pointers?

Comment: This is out of date

Answer (score 3):

An updated answer for Android Studio Chipmunk and Gradle 7.3.3

This is in the project level gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.7'
    }
}
```

These are in the module level gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}
```

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        jacoco {
            includeNoLocationClasses = true
            excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, the task that runs the tests.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
    reports {
        xml.getRequired().set(true)
        html.getRequired().set(true)
    }

    def fileFilter = [
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*Test*.*',
            'android/**/*.*'
    ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(
            dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug",
            excludes: fileFilter
    )
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from(files([mainSrc]))
    classDirectories.from(files([debugTree]))
    executionData.from(fileTree(
            dir: "$buildDir",
            includes: [
                    "outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
                    "outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*/coverage.ec"
            ]
    ))
    
}
```

`"$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug"` is for Kotlin. Change to `"$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug"` for Java.

`testDebugUnitTest` runs unit tests and creates a coverage report at `"outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec"`.
Note that path may differ. I searched for "exec" in the app folder to find it.

`createDebugCoverageReport` runs the Android tests and creates a coverage report at `"outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*/coverage.ec"`. Note that this path may also differ. I searched for "coverage.ec" in the app folder to find it.

Finally, to run the tests and create a coverage report you can create a run configuration to run "clean jacocoTestReport" or tap ctrl twice in Android Studio and run "./gradlew clean jacocoTestReport" which will create the run configuration for you.

Comment: There is a bug where this solution fails due to Hilt somehow ruining coverage due to the way it compiles stuff.