# Exception in Android App: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline;

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, jacoco

### Problem

So I integrated Jetpack Compose dependencies in the application module. But the below exception is occurring whenever the app is started/launched. It's failing in the `Application` class.

**Stacktrace:**

```
2021-10-22 11:16:01.079 16281-16281/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 16281
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline;
        at com.example.app.MyApplication.attachBaseContext(MyApplication.java:719)
        at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:361)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1159)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1324)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2172)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~MsNoI2GIvO6hDqGPC9BKfw==/com.example-jknI-wJelwi0a-NSFCz0ig==/base.apk"]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.app.MyApplication.attachBaseContext(MyApplication.java:719) 
        at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:361) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1159) 
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1324) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:298) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2172) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/~~MsNoI2GIvO6hDqGPC9BKfw==/com.example-jknI-wJelwi0a-NSFCz0ig==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:379)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:85)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:398)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:129)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:104)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:981)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1038)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1270)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2750)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7128)
2021-10-22 11:16:01.080 16281-16281/com.example E/AndroidRuntime:       ... 8 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/~~MsNoI2GIvO6hDqGPC9BKfw==/com.example-jknI-wJelwi0a-NSFCz0ig==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:379)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:85)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:398)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:129)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:104)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:981)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1038)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1270)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2750)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7128)
                ... 8 more
```

### My Setup

- IDE: Android Studio Arctic Fox - Stable | Patch 3
- Java JDK 11
- Kotlin 1.5.30
- Jetpack Compose 1.0.3
- Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.2
- Gradle Wrapper Version 7.0.2
- JaCoCo Version 0.8.7

build.gradle:

```
jacoco {
  toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

android {
  ...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}

buildTypes {
  debug {
    testCoverageEnabled true
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem when trying to use ActivityScenario in a test with Jacoco coverage set up.

Comment: If you remove Jacoco, you won't get the error.

Comment: Yeah removing it fixed this issue. But isn't there any way?

Comment: I have a working configuration here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72456273/13264143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the issue is very interesting.

Our project has remote submodules which were also using JaCoCo and in the main project we upgraded the Android Gradle Plugin version and not upgraded AGP in remote submodules then this issue was occurring. This is because those submodules also use the JaCoCo plugin.

Once we upgraded all submodules which were using the JaCoCo plugin and updated respective versions in the main application, this issue got resolved.

Earlier we were using AGP 4.2.2 and this issue was coming after upgrading AGP to 7.x.x.